# Order comments from certain users first, then by comment score

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

In a Rails 4 project I have `articles` which `has_many comments`.

I’m trying to show a list of comments under an article ordered by the comment `score` (an integer column in the comment table), but where **comments from a small number of users are shown first** (eg. admins & mods). These users would be passed as an array of user_ids to the query (`user_id` is also a column in the comment table):

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # article_id  :integer
  # user_id     :integer
  # score       :integer

  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user

  scope :by_users, -> (user_ids) { order("user_id IN (?), score DESC", user_ids) }
```

Thus:

```
some_article.comments.by_users([1,2,3])
```

This scope gives a syntax error, and I can’t quite work out a query that orders comments so that ALL an article’s comments are returned, shown first from users with a user_id in the passed array, then secondarily ordered by comment score.

**Update:**

mahemoff’s great conditional idea doesn’t work for Postgres, but lead to this non-working attempt:

```
scope :by_users, -> (user_ids) { order("case when (user_id IN (?)) then 0 else 1 end, score DESC", user_ids) }
```

Which gives me a PostgreSQL syntax error relating to the placeholder `?` that I haven’t been able to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :by_users, -> (user_ids) { order("if(user_id IN (#{ids.join ','}), 0, 1), score DESC") }
```

Comment: (1) PostgreSQL doesn't have an `if` function like that, a CASE expression would be portable. (2) Doesn't ActiveRecord want `order([expr_with_placeholders, value])` in order to use placeholders in an `order` call?

Comment: mu is correct, Postgres uses a `case` switch for conditional logic - which using mahemoff’s idea gives me this non-working attempt: `order("case when (user_id IN (?)) then 0 else 1 end, score DESC", user_ids)` where the problem seems to be with the `?` placeholder for `user_ids`...

Comment: @dj. you can try using an array then, like mu suggests. Also you don't *have to* use the placeholder if it's really a headache. At least in dev you can try using just string interpolation like `user_id in (#{ids.join ','})` and worry about sanitising it later.

Comment: Hmmm... `order` in Rails can’t use a `?` placeholder like `where` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

With *mahemoff* & *mu is too short*’s help and suggestions, this is my working scope:

```
scope :by_users, -> (user_ids) { order([sanitize_sql("case when (user_id IN (#{user_ids.join(',')})) then 0 else 1 end"), "score DESC" ]) }
```

It’s somewhat imperfect, as Rails’ `order` apparently doesn’t support the `?` placeholder, so instead I’ve used string interpolation and (even though `user_ids` isn’t user exposed) sanitized the sql.

*...a frustrating problem with this though,* is that it’s impossible to use `.last` to retrieve the final record. `some_article.by_users[1,2].last` now throws an error as AR can’t work out where to reverse the ordering:

```
ORDER BY case when (user_id IN (1 DESC, 2)) then 0 else 1 end DESC, score ASC LIMIT 1
```

sigh...